# Grep issues with if statement in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, grep, tail

I'm having an issue with `tail` & `grep` in shell script if statement. If I run `tail -5 mylog.log | grep -c "Transferred:            0"` in shell, it runs as it should, but in this shell script if statement:

```
# Parse log for results
if [ tail -1 "$LOGFILE" | grep -c "Failed" ] ; then
        RESULT=$(tail -1 "$LOGFILE")
elif [ tail -5 "$LOGFILE" | grep -c "Transferred:            0" ] ; then
        RESULT=""
else
        RESULT=$(tail -5 "$LOGFILE")
fi
```

I get

```
... [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

for both of the grep lines.

It's clearly to do with the closing `]` being seen as part of the grep (and thus missing) but I'm using the correct whitespace so I can't figure out what's going on? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
PJ

Comment: `[ ]` is not part of `if` syntax. It's a **separate command**.

Comment: And frankly, this is just plain inefficient -- it's calling `tail` at least twice. Much, much better to call it once and then test the result in native bash.

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: How would I get around this by calling `tail` only once? Btw, thanks for the shellcheck.net.

Comment: I've extended my answer to show an approach with only one `tail` invocation (and no `grep` invocations at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Immediate Issue / Immediate Fix

Take out the brackets.

```
if tail -1 "$logfile" | grep -q "Failed" ; then
```

`[` is not part of `if` syntax. Rather, it's a synonym for the command named `test` (which is typically both available as a shell builtin and an external binary, like `/bin/test` or `/usr/bin/test`).

Thus, your original code was running `[ tail -1 "$logfile"`, and piping its result to `grep -q "Failed" ]`. The first `[` was failing because it didn't see an ending `]` -- which is mandatory when invoked by that name rather than with the name `test` -- and also because its parameters weren't a test it knew how to parse; and the second `grep` didn't know what the `]` it was being piped meant, trying to find a file by that name.

---

#### Other Notes

Try to run external commands -- like `tail` -- as little as possible. There's a very significant startup cost.

Consider the following, which runs `tail` only once:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- IMPORTANT: bash, not /bin/sh

last_5_lines="$(tail -5 "$logfile")"
last_line="${last_5_lines##*$'\n'}"
if [[ $last_line = *Failed* ]]; then
  result=$last_line
elif [[ $last_5_lines =~ 'Transferred:'[[:space:]]+'0' ]]; then
  result=''
else
  result=$last_5_lines
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: BTW, to explain the all-lowercase variables -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html; all-uppercase names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas variables with at least one lowercase character in their names are reserved for application use. That's only black-letter POSIX for environment variables, but since setting a regular shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable, the convention necessarily applies to them as well if you want to avoid conflicts.